# With Gnome 3, does VNC allow multiple sessions with same uid?

Tags: solaris, gnome3

On Solaris, I am trying something similar to (https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/525387-VNC-Multiple-Connections-with-same-User-Id-not-working-under-SuSE12-1)  - to get two sessions with the same uid. The first session is ok and starts gnome-shell but in the second session, I get past the gdm greeter but gnome-shell doesn't start.  If I use two different uid's I don't have the problem.